# mysql_config_editor not included in MySQL APT Repository?

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I've installed MySQL from [MySQL APT Repository](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/). Now I want to run "mysql_config_editor" to encrypt my .mylogin.cnf, but it displays:

```
The program 'mysql_config_editor' is currently not installed. To run 'mysql_config_editor' please ask your administrator to install the package 'mysql-client-5.6'
```

I could install mysql-client-5.6, but then it uninstalls my MySQL APT Repository packages and replaces with older, "Ubuntu original" packages.

Can I just extract mysql_config_editor binary from mysql-client-5.6 deb package, or maybe it's not a good idea? And why this binary isn't in MySQL APT Repository?

Comment: That's not an Ubuntu problem, that's a problem with the MySQL repository. File a bug report with them.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @muru. MySQL answered that I should install "DEB Development Headers" package from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/, which is not included in repository.

Comment: You can post that as an answer. Maybe it will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @muru suggested, I sent this question to MySQL and they replied that I should install "DEB Development Headers" package from [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql), which is not included in repository.

For Ubuntu 14.04 and MySQL 5.6.21 it would be:

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.21-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.21-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb
rm libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.21-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: please note this will stop/start the already running server (if any)